# Aframe - How to render HUD on top of everything else

Tags: aframe

The A-Frame [camera docs](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/camera.html) say to create a HUD like this:

```
<a-entity camera look-controls>
  <a-entity geometry="primitive: plane; height: 0.2; width: 0.2" position="0 0 -1"
            material="color: gray; opacity: 0.5"></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

However, this causes the HUD element to be clipped by in-game objects. Normally HUDs are rendered on a separate layer above all the other game objects. Is there a simple way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to:

- Set `renderer.sortObjects = true;`
- Set a the render order of the entity `this.el.object3D.renderOrder = 100;`
- Disable the material depth test `material.depthTest = false;`

I created a simple `overlay` component that easily applies the above to any entity.

```
  AFRAME.registerComponent("overlay", {
        dependencies: ['material'],
        init: function () {
          this.el.sceneEl.renderer.sortObjects = true;
          this.el.object3D.renderOrder = 100;
          this.el.components.material.material.depthTest = false;
        }
  });
```

```
<a-entity camera look-controls wasd-controls position="0 1.6 0">
  <a-plane id="hud" overlay rotation="0 0 0" position="0 0 -2" width="1" height="1" color="purple" shadow></a-plane>
</a-entity>
```

Example on [glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/cypress-responsible-baker?path=index.html%3A24%3A0)

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't work when used with [decals](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/geometries/DecalGeometry) which I'm doing, but this technically answered my question.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/fuzzy-spiritual-skipjack) with decals to show the issue. I added comments to lines in the `paintable.js` component that were suggested to fix the problem, but they don't

Comment: Not sure what it's the expected behavior of the decal example.

Comment: You click to shoot decals at the scene, and I'd expect the HUD to be rendered on top of everything. However, the decals are rendered on top of the HUD.

Comment: Notice that the decal material has a transparent material. Those are always rendered after "non-transparent" ones like the cursor. Setting the hud material to transparent solves the issue: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/adaptive-prickly-preface?path=index.html%3A26%3A65